# Vector out of bounds while reading a TXT file

Tags: java, string, file, vector

I'm trying to read the values of a .TXT file and store these values in various vectors (the values in the file are separated by a comma, I'm using `.Split ()` method to get these values), the problem that is appearing to me is that my vector aux is exceeding the limit after the first writing.

The code:

```
String[] iltxt = new String[49];
String[] ertxt = new String[49];
String[] tcsetxt = new String[49];
String[] arttxt = new String[49];
String[] rmtxt  = new String[49];
String[] burtxt  = new String[49];
String[] toftxt = new String[49];
String[] atgtxt = new String[49];
String[] nrtxt = new String[49];
String[] hlab27txt = new String[49];
String[] djtxt = new String[49];
String[] dltxt = new String[49];
String[] rctxt = new String[49];
String[] dctxt = new String[49];
String[] mobtxt = new String[49];
String[] dtstxt = new String[49];
String[] sintxt = new String[49];
String[] diagnosticotxt = new String[49];
String[] aux = new String[18];
int cont = 1;  
      try {
      FileReader arq = new FileReader("File.txt");
      BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
      String linha = lerArq.readLine(); 
      aux = linha.split(",");
      //STORES THE VALUES OF THE FIRST LINE INTO THE VECTORS
      dltxt[0] = aux[0];
      rctxt[0] = aux[1];
      dctxt[0] = aux[2];
      mobtxt[0] = aux[3];
      dtstxt[0] = aux[4];
      iltxt[0] = aux[5];
      ertxt[0] = aux[6];
      tcsetxt[0] = aux[7];
      arttxt[0] = aux[8];
      rmtxt[0] = aux[9];
      burtxt[0] = aux[10];
      toftxt[0] = aux[11];
      sintxt[0] = aux[12];
      atgtxt[0] = aux[13];
      nrtxt[0] = aux[14];
      hlab27txt[0] = aux[15];
      djtxt[0] = aux[16];
      diagnosticotxt[0] = aux[17];
      //CLEAN THE VECTOR AUX TO THE NEXT READ
      aux = null;
      while (linha != null) {
            //READ THE VALUES OF THE SECOND TO THE LAST LINE AND STORES INTO THE VECTORS
            linha = lerArq.readLine(); 
            aux = linha.split(",");
            dltxt[cont] = aux[0];
            rctxt[cont] = aux[1];
            dctxt[cont] = aux[2];
            mobtxt[cont] = aux[3];
            dtstxt[cont] = aux[4];
            iltxt[cont] = aux[5];
            ertxt[cont] = aux[6];
            tcsetxt[cont] = aux[7];
            arttxt[cont] = aux[8];
            rmtxt[cont] = aux[9];
            burtxt[cont] = aux[10];
            toftxt[cont] = aux[11];
            sintxt[cont] = aux[12];
            atgtxt[cont] = aux[13];
            nrtxt[cont] = aux[14];
            hlab27txt[cont] = aux[15];
            djtxt[cont] = aux[16];
            diagnosticotxt[cont] = aux[17];
            //CLEAN THE AUX VECTOR
            aux = null;
            //INCREMENT THE COUNTER TO SAVE VALUES IN THE NEXT POSITIONS OF THE VECTORS
            cont++;
      }
      arq.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Error while open the file: %s.\n",
            e.getMessage());
      }
```

The values of the TXT File:

```
Sim,Sim,Sim,Ilimitado,Sim,Ausente,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Negativo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Ausente,Moderado,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Ausente,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Moderado,Importante,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Muito Importante,Muito Importante,Importante,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Muito Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumática

Sim,Não,Sim,Normal,Sim,Moderado,Importante,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante 

Sim,Sim,Sim,Limitado,Sim,Moderado,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Muito Importante,Ausente,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Ausente,Leve,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Negativo,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Muito Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Negativo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Importante,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumática

Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Moderado,Ausente,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Ausente,Moderado,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Artrite Reumatica

Sim,Sim,Não,Normal,Sim,Ausente,Moderado,Leve,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Sim,Não,Sim,Normal,Não,Ausente,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Ausente,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Sim,Sim,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Importante,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Moderado,Moderado,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Importante,Moderado,Sim,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Importante,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Sim,Sim,Não,Normal,Sim,Ausente,Importante,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Moderado,Não,Sim,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Ausente,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Negativo,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Moderado,Moderado,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Moderado,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Ausente,Ausente,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Negativo,Não,Artrite Reumática

Sim,Sim,Não,Limitado,Sim,Leve,Importante,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Negativo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Moderado,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Sim,Sim,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Ausente,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Sim,Sim,Não,Limitado,Sim,Importante,Muito Importante,Importante,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Muito Importante,Ausente,Moderado,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Artrite Reumática

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Leve,Moderado,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Sim,Sim,Sim,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Muito Importante,Moderado,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Positivo,Sim,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Ausente,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Sim,Sim,Não,Normal,Não,Ausente,Ausente,Não,Não,Sim,não,Não,Não,Sim,não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Sim,Sim,Sim,Normal,Não,Ausente,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Sim,Moderado,Importante,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Leve,Importante,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Leve,Moderado,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Importante,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica

Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota

Não,Não,Não,Normal,não,Moderado,Importante,Não,Não,Sim,Não,não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
```

**The error that appears while executing the code:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

**The line of the error:**

```
rctxt[cont] = aux[1];
```

Someone knows how to fix this? (Sorry about some words in portugues, I am from Brazil)

Comment: Please post the rest of the stacktrace and show us which line causes the exception.

Comment: You should consider creating a class to hold your data. Then you will only need one array of these objects.

Comment: I am using a JFRAME, I will update the post showing the line of the error.

Comment: JFrame is unrelated top your current question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some of the lines do not have any text (empty lines).

The split on these lines will not produce an 18 length Strings array.

try

```
if (arr.length < 18)
   continue;
```

Also as mentioned above, having an Object that encapsulates this data would make you code a lot more readable.

**Edit**

For clarification

You have this code

```
 while (linha != null) {
        linha = lerArq.readLine(); 
        aux = linha.split(",");
```

now check the size of the `aux` array and if not 18 then skip this line

```
    if (aux.length < 18) {
       System.err.println (linha + " does not have enough values");
       continue;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I removed all the empty lines In my file, now the same error occours in the last line `diagnosticotxt[cont] = aux[17]` , I didn't use the condition that you said because I don't understood it. Can you explain again?

Answer (score 1):

The exception happens because you seperated the lines with *empty lines* and you 
do not check if there are actually 18 tokens. 
Either you remove those empty lines or you add a condition like so:

```
linha = lerArq.readLine();

aux = linha.split(",");
if(aux.length != 18)
    continue;
```

Also you have a little problem with one of your lines (35). That line has just 17 tokens and causes the next *ArrayOutOfBoundsException* if you do not use the condition but remove the empty lines in your File.txt

Comment: Ehm yes sorry my bad. Gonna fix that. Still early in the morning here -.-'

Comment: Ok, I removed all the empty lines In my file, now the same error occours in the last line diagnosticotxt[cont] = aux[17] , I didn't use the condition that you said because I don't understood it. Can you explain again?

Comment: @Mutante the condition checks if your array of tokens that you received from the split method has not the lenght oft 18. if that is the case the continue lets the program "jump" back to the loops start and iterates through the next line. The exception you encounter now is also descriped in my answer. One oft your entriss in your file has just 17 tokens. Therefore trying to access the 18th element ([17]) causes an exception

Comment: Can you update my post with this answer? I can't see where I put the condition you mentioned to avoid the last exception.